# JavaScript - tooltip div on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'd like to implement this situation: user hovers link and on his screen appears div with additional information.

There is no problem, to generate div with absolute position, populate data and display it with jQuery, but the problem is with maintainability. I want to separate logic and view. What if I'd like to change page layout in the future? How programmer will know, that some part of page exist in JavaScript file?

Is it some elegant way to separate view (in my case HTML structure) and logic (data obtained from server in JSON using JS script) and combine them? Is it any ... templating engine or something like that in JavaScript?

Comment: Have a look a HTML5 `data`-attributes: http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/

Comment: Why dont you just use the title attribute? `<a href="something.com" title="This will link you to something">something</a>`

Comment: This have to be custom html div tag. For example, I'd like to use image with few links and comments there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap does all this and more: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips

To put it in:

```
$('#example').tooltip(options)
```

And the markup being:

```
<div class="tooltip">
  <div class="tooltip-inner">
    Tooltip text here!
   </div>
  <div class="tooltip-arrow"></div>
</div>
```

Go to the link for a more detailed explanation on how to implement it

Comment: Looks great for me :)

Comment: Good :) There are also other (maybe more customisable) UI's out there like bootstrap

Comment: Such as: http://designmodo.github.io/Flat-UI/     To me, the flat UI is awesome, scroll through all the samples, theres a tooltip in there somewhere...

Comment: Hey, if this worked for you.. may I ask for a green tick on my answer?

Comment: Glad I could help, is there anything else you need?

Answer (score 2):

You can generate your HTML entries like this

```
<a>
    My Cool Link
    <div class="tooltip">
        This link is awesome!
    </div>
</a>
```

And use CSS to style the tooltip:
(The important part is `a:hover .tooltip` and everything except `background` on `.tooltip`

```
a {
    display: inline-block;
}
a:hover .tooltip {
    visibility: visible;
}
.tooltip {
    position: relative;
    top: 20px;
    left: -50%;
    display: inline;
    visibility: hidden;
    background: #eee;
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/4K7sB/

Then you just need to populate the elements with the correct text using JS.

Answer (score 0):

You can alter the Title="information" dynamicaly by some program or script and use the following code to display it as a tool tip,found it on net

http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2012/11/how-to-create-a-simple-css3-tooltip/

Answer (score 0):

Just add title attribute in div tag like below code....

```
<div  title="First Div">StackOverFlow StackOverFlow StackOverFlow 
StackOverFlow StackOverFlow StackOverFlow StackOverFlow StackOverFlow 
StackOverFlow </div>
</div>
<br /><br />
<div  title="Second Div">StackOverFlow StackOverFlow StackOverFlow 
StackOverFlow StackOverFlow StackOverFlow StackOverFlow StackOverFlow 
StackOverFlow </div>
</div>
```

just copy paste and check.